# Is this function one to one?

Tags: real-analysis

I recently came across this problem:

> Find out whether the function $\phi$ given below has one to one mapping:$$\phi(f)(x)=\int^x_0f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$where $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ and $x\in\mathbb R$.

In my opinion, its not an one-to-one function.

When we start with $\phi_1(f_1)(x_1)$=$\phi_2(f_2)(x_2)$,
we can have $f_1=x$ and $x_1=1$, and $f_2=\frac{1}{6}$ and $x_2=3$. This clearly shows that even though $\phi_1(f_1)(x_1)=\phi_2(f_2)(x_2)$, but $f_1 \neq f_2$.

It will be of great help if someone can help confirm whether my reasoning is correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @saad for pointing that out! I hadn't typed the question correctly. I have made the changes. Please check the question again.

Comment: [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements)

Comment: Your argument is on the right track, but the line of reasoning should be that $\phi (f_1, x_1) = \phi (f_2, x_2) $ but $(f_1, x_1) \neq (f_2,x_2)$

Comment: $\phi$, as  a mapping from a function space to a function space is one-to -one. I think that is what is intended.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean: Whether for a given $f$ the function $\phi(f) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is injective for all $x$ or whether the function $\phi : C^\infty(\mathbb R) \to   C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is injective.

Comment: The question asked whether $\phi(f,x)$ is injective

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi $ is linear you need only to see what is it kernel. So if $$\int_0^{x} f(t)\;dt =0$$ what can we tell about $f$. Since it is continuos we see that $f\equiv 0$ and so $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Hi @Aqua, Thanks for your answer! I had a couple of queries, can you please help? You have mentioned that as $\phi$ is linear, we can directly look at the kernel. It's my first encounter with an example of this kind. Can you please provide a link to study more about this method of solving? Also, you have equated the integral to zero. Can you please explain the reasoning behind it? Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Algebraic_classifications_of_linear_transformations